# I cannot find my solution explorer in visual studio

Tags: c#

I m using visual studio 2012 and my problem is minor .. and that is whenever i create mvc4 web application it doesnot show solution explorer to add class library. only my project gets displayed.

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort, try to resolve the problem before posting it here, if you've tried something, indicate what steps you took and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the actual Solution Explorer window you can activate it by going to the View menu and clicking on Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. In my case, it got resolved by following the below steps:

1. Click on Tools.
2. Click on "Import and Export settings".
3. Select "Reset all settings".
4. Click on "No Just reset my setting".
5. Click on next.
6. Click on finish.